# Diálogo para pegar apenas o caminho local de uma pasta

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um campo em um formulário html, onde deve ser inserido o caminho (path) de uma pasta do Windows (EX: C:\pasta1\pasta11), onde este campo é do tipo **text** mesmo.

Porém, para facilitar, gostaria de fazer um diálogo, igual ao input do tipo file, mas a intenção não é pegar os arquivos, mas sim a string com o path da pasta selecionada.

Como devo proceder?
Obrigado.

Comment: Creio que por motivos de segurança não seja possivel fazer isso, mas se a intenção é escolher uma pasta para salvar deixe o arquivo como download normal...

Comment: Na verdade não é pra salvar. A minha intenção é pegar o path e então trabalhar encima desse path com o DirectoryIterator do PHP, pela simplicidade dele.

Esse script é executado apenas no próprio servidor.

Comment: ainda não consegui entender exatamente o que você quer fazer e como vai funcionar

Comment: Acho que ficou meio vago mesmo, mas vou tentar explicar exatamente o que o script faz (mas que gostaria dessa melhoria). Atualmente eu acesso um formulário no localhost, onde existe um campo para eu indicar uma pasta onde estão os arquivos que eu quero trabalhar. Após enviar o formulário, um script PHP percorre esta pasta e executa uma aplicação (.exe), passando cada um dos arquivos da pasta como parâmetro (um de cada vez). Atualmente isso tudo já funciona, mas a minha intenção, para facilitar, é ter a possibilidade de escolher a pasta por um diálogo, ao invés de um input de texto comum.

Comment: para você capturar endereços vocẽ pode utilizar a requisição `$_SERVER`, para ver os tipos como por exemplo `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, faça um: `var_dump($_SERVER)`; Também existe `dirname(__FILE__)`, `dirname(__DIR__)`. basta fazer um `echo dirname(__DIR__)` que você já verá o resultado, para windows use a constante do PHP para separador de diretórios: `PATH_SEPARATOR`, e para unix: `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Obter o AbsolutePath do input type="file"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106904/obter-o-absolutepath-do-input-type-file)