# Obter o AbsolutePath do input type="file"

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou tentando obter o caminho completo do diretório através do input do tipo file, porém até agora só conseguir pegar uma pasta anterior, por exemplo, tenho a pasta no caminho C:/user/Documents/Images/Ontem então eu gostaria de pegar esse caminho todo, mas só consigo pegar a pasta Ontem, o codigo que estou fazendo é

```
$('#pasta').change(
    function absolutepath(e){   
    var aqrs;
    var theFiles = e.target.files;
    alert(theFiles[0].webkitRelativePath);
});
```

Com esse código acima ele pegar o primeiro arquivo com a pasta com o input abaixo:

```
<input type="file" id="pasta"  multiple webkitdirectory />
```

Como faço para pegar o caminho todo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nao é possível.**

Por medida de segurança os navegadores não permitem que você saiba o Path Absoluto do arquivo do usuário.

E você só consegue visualizar o nome da pasta anterior porque a propriedade `webkitdirectory` retorna a path relativo da sua pasta.

> Dê acordo com a especificação do **HTML5**, um controle de upload não
>   deve revelar o caminho real do arquivo selecionado. <sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> [THE MYSTERY OF C:\FAKEPATH UNVEILED](http://martinivanov.net/2009/06/09/the-mystery-of-cfakepath-unveiled/)

Comment: Na verdade, estou passando por algo semelhante. Estou fazendo um upload com redimensionamento de imagens, preciso jogar o caminho desta imagem num input, e estou sofrendo para fazer isso. Existe outro caminho? Algo que possa a ser feito? @Laerte, qual sua sugestão?

Comment: Cara infelizmente isso é uma limitação imposta pela especificação e implementada pelos navegadores, é uma medida de segurança não há nada que possamos fazer, mas no seu caso você quer replicar a imagem enviado pelo usuário pra outro input?

Comment: As imagens vão para uma pasta do servidor, o nome do arquivo é um md5. Eu preciso do caminho para salvar no banco. Esse caminho, eu lanço no input. No outro sistema que eu usava, a imagem aparecia, eu clicava com o botão direito e pegava o caminho da imagem. Mas não quero quer seja assim, prefiro automático, o usuário acaba se perdendo em coisas simples...